# Confusion with member copying of class

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

After studying the member copying and the assignment operator in C++,
and looking at " [member copying of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320675/member-copying-of-class/5320744#5320744) " which explains the conditions where default assignment operator cannot be generated. I am not very clear about the concepts as the following example I tried actually works on g++4.5

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Y{
  int& x;
  const int cx;
public:
  Y(int v1,int v2)
    :x(v1),cx(v2)
  {}
  int getx(){return x;}
  int getcx(){return cx;}
};

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  Y y1(a,a);
  Y y2 = y1;//assignment
  cout<<y1.getx()<<" "<<y1.getcx();
  return 0;
}
```

So where am I not getting the concepts. Please suggest other examples (if possible) so that I can understand better.

Comment: Note that `Y y2 = y1;` is not an assignment, but a copy-construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Y y2 = y1;` is not an assignment. It's a copy constructor call. If you declare and initialize a variable on the same line, a one parameter constructor is called with the right hand side of the equals sign as the parameter. There's nothing about `Y` that prevents the default copy constructor from being instantiated (and called).

Try the following:

```
Y y1(10, 10);
Y y2(11, 11);
y2 = y1;
```

This should fail, although I can't test it right now.

Comment: thanks ... declaring Y y2(a,b); y2 = y1; is giving the error message i wanted to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Y{
  int& x;

  public:
  Y(int v1,int v2)
    :x(v1),cx(v2)
  {} // v1 ceases to exist from this point
};
```

`x` is a reference variable to an int. Now you are initializing it to `v1`, which means `x` is an alias to `v1` itself. The scope of `v1` is in the constructor alone. With that said -

```
 Y y2 = y1;//assignment => Not assignment. It is initialization.
```

is equivalent to

```
 Y y2(y1);  // compiler is looking for the overloaded constructor ( ie. copy constructor in this case ).

 class Y{
      public:
       Y ( const Y & other ); // copy constructor
       // ...
 };
```

Comment: yes you are right, but the program works as is. i mean why there is no error message even i am wondering. after the constructor returns what is stored in `x`?

Comment: @Aditya Kumar - Yeah, I see my self of it compiled on gcc (http://ideone.com/RZxKC). Let's wait and see if any one is going to correct us.

Comment: This is incorrect. The compiler will provide an assignment operator and a copy constructor as long as none exists. The existence of user-defined constructors does not affect this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Y{
  int& x;
  const int cx;
public:
  Y(int v1,int v2)
    :x(v1),cx(v2)
  {}
  int getx(){return x;}
  int getcx(){return cx;}
};

int main()
{
  int a = 10;
  Y y1(a,a);
  Y y2 = y1;//NOT assignment. Object is yet to be constructed, so calls copy c'tor
  y2 = y1; // assignment operator is called
  cout<<y1.getx()<<" "<<y1.getcx();
  return 0;
}

/*
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp||In member function 'Y& Y::operator=(const Y&)':|
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp|4|error: non-static reference member 'int& Y::x', can't use default assignment operator|
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp|4|error: non-static const member 'const int Y::cx', can't use default assignment operator|
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\Workspaces\CodeBlocks\Test\main.cpp|20|note: synthesized method 'Y& Y::operator=(const Y&)' first required here |
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class contains members which cannot be default-constructed or assigned, namely:

- References
- Constants

Therefore, no default constructor or assignment operator can be implied for your class. For example, you have to write your own constructor:

```
class Foo
{
  const int a;
  int     & b;
public:
  Foo(int val, int & modify_me) :
    a(val) ,      // initialize the constant
    b(modify_me)  // bind the reference
  { }
};
```

It is clear that you cannot default-construct `Foo` (i.e. <s>`Foo x;`</s>). It is also clear that you cannot reassign objects of class `Foo` (i.e. <s>`x = y;`</s>), because you cannot reassign references or constants.

By giving your class a reference or a constant member, you actually confer reference or constant semantics on the class itself, if you will, so this should be a fairly immediate logical consequence. For example, reassignment probably doesn't even make sense semantically, because your class is supposed to embody a constant concept.

However, note that you **can** make *copies* of your class: That's because you can make "copies" of references (i.e. furhter aliases), and copies of constants. Therefore, a copy constructor *is* available implicitly, by simply applying copy-construction member-by member. So you *can* say:

```
int n;
Foo x(15, n);

Foo y(x);
Foo z = x;  // these two are identical!
```

This results in two further objects `y` and `z` which have `y.a == 15` and `z.a == 15`, and `y.b` and `z.b` are all references to `n`. (Don't be [confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436102/question-regarding-c-copy-constructor-call) by the two alternative syntaxes at the end; both invoke the copy constructor.)